# activate and deactivate mysql record using php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi I'm working on user management system. I'm displays all records from db and add, edit and delete operations are successfully performed. now I'm need to display in home page as only active records from Mysql table. i have 2 links in my admin control one is activate and another is deactivate. if i click activate the records will display in home page and deactivate means records will hide in home page. i'm inserted field status with

```
datatype enum('active','deactive')`.
```

my coding are below. In coding what changes i need it?

**Index.php:**

```
<form method="post">
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Title:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="author" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Publisher Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Copyright Year</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {      
    include 'db.php';

                    $title=$_POST['title'] ;
                    $author= $_POST['author'] ;                 
                    $name=$_POST['name'] ;
                    $copy=$_POST['copy'] ;

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO `books`(Title,Author,PublisherName,CopyrightYear) 
         VALUES ('$title','$author','$name','$copy')"); 


            }
?>
</form>
<table border="1">

            <?php
            include("db.php");


            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books");

            while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $id = $test['BookID'];  
                echo "<tr align='center'>"; 
                echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['BookID']."</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['Title']."</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['Author']. "</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['PublisherName']. "</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['CopyrightYear']. "</font></td>"; 
                echo"<td> <a href ='view.php?BookID=$id'>Edit</a>";
                echo"<td> <a href ='view.php?BookID=$id'>Activate</a>";
                echo"<td> <a href ='view.php?BookID=$id'>Deactivate</a>";
                echo"<td> <a href ='del.php?BookID=$id'><center>Delete</center></a>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
            mysql_close($conn);
            ?>
</table>

View.php:
<?php
require("db.php");
$id =$_REQUEST['BookID'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE BookID  = '$id'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result) 
        {
        die("Error: Data not found..");
        }
                $Title=$test['Title'] ;
                $Author= $test['Author'] ;                  
                $PublisherName=$test['PublisherName'] ;
                $CopyrightYear=$test['CopyrightYear'] ;

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{   
    $title_save = $_POST['title'];
    $author_save = $_POST['author'];
    $name_save = $_POST['name'];
    $copy_save = $_POST['copy'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE books SET Title ='$title_save', Author ='$author_save',
         PublisherName ='$name_save',CopyrightYear ='$copy_save' WHERE BookID = '$id'")
                or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo "Saved!";

    header("Location: index.php");          
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $Title ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $Author ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Publisher Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $PublisherName ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Copyright Year</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php echo $CopyrightYear ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="save" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**del.php:**

```
<?php
  include("db.php");  

    $id =$_REQUEST['BookID'];


    // sending query
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM books WHERE BookID = '$id'")
    or die(mysql_error());      

    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

please give some ideas or codings. this is first time i'm using this concept.??

Answer (score 4):

While Using active deactive logic..

You have to follow following steps:-

> 1. You have to create some flag status with enum value for active and
>      deactive.
> 2. while fetching data from database you have to give condition to fetch only active record.
> 3. If you have active or deactive button you have to update your record
>      based on that.

If you will follow these step it will work!!

Answer (score 1):

#### It is not a good idea to use `enum` for a `boolean` type, as it occupies more memory.

You can have something like a `active` flag in the database of the records. Since already you have a unique ID for each row, you can just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `books`;
```

#### Output

```
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------+
| id | title                 | pub                  | author         | copy | active |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------+
|  1 | A Matter of Time      | Outskirts Press      | Michael Bowler | 2010 |      0 |
|  2 | The Promise of Change | Soul Mate Publishing | Rebecca Heflin | 2011 |      0 |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------+
```

And for the `active`, you can either set `0` to hide or `1` to show! :)

#### Now lets activate the book, `A Matter of Time`. It has an ID `1`.

```
UPDATE `books` SET `active` = '1' WHERE  `books`.`id` = 1;
```

#### Output

```
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------+
| id | title                 | pub                  | author         | copy | active |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------+
|  1 | A Matter of Time      | Outskirts Press      | Michael Bowler | 2010 |      1 |
|  2 | The Promise of Change | Soul Mate Publishing | Rebecca Heflin | 2011 |      0 |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------+
```

#### Lets get only the active books:

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `active` = 1;
```

#### Output

```
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------+
| id | title                 | pub                  | author         | copy | active |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------+
|  1 | A Matter of Time      | Outskirts Press      | Michael Bowler | 2010 |      1 |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------+
```

#### Using this you can retrieve the active books alone. Now to deactivate the book:

```
UPDATE `books` SET `active` = '0' WHERE  `books`.`id` = 1;
```

#### The PHP Code

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `active` = 1");
    while (false !== ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
        echo $data["title"];
?>
```

Format the code according to your needs. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you insert or update data just also add status field which stored your data or record status.

And when you displayed in query user where condition like `SELECT * FROM books where status='active'`.

This will work for you just try.

Answer (score 0):

This active and deactivate a account. create a status column in  database table give type int  and  if u insert a database it automatically  take 0 and when select  table give  condition where status="1" 1 means active and 0 is deactivate.
for ex: select * from login where status='1';
[Demo](http://www.crackerworld.in/2013/02/active-and-deactive-account-in-php.html)